# Update Custom Filter gives ambiguous error message

Tags: bug, tag-filters

Using a custom filter, I clicked the Edit button, made a change, clicked Update Filter.  The dialog responded with the following:

[image]

I get that this probably means my filter named "Java" happens to duplicate the criteria in "My Filter", but the error message could be clearer.

Something along the lines of

> The filter you are trying to save (name of filter) duplicates the criteria in an existing filter named (name of other filter).  That is not permitted.

CLARIFICATION (in response to a comment):  I started out with two filters previously defined, `Java` and `My Filter`.  I don't remember creating `My Filter`, I think it's been there for years.  I edited `Java`, made one small change and clicked `Update Filter`.  That's when the error shown above was displayed.  It took me a minute to parse the error message and understand what it was saying.  I originally thought this was a bug, but now I see it's just an ambiguous message.

Comment: Just to be clear: was this when editing the filter "My Filter" (and renaming it to "Java"), or were you editing a different filter and the edit coincidentally caused it to be the same as "My Filter"?

Comment: @Marijn Clarified in original post.

Comment: Or simply display the error message as soon as the user clicks the "Save or update custom filter" button (instead of on the dialog that asks for the name of the filter). That way, it's clear that the message has nothing to do with the name itself.

Comment: The "that is not permitted" part is implied by the fact that it is shown in an error message, no need to specify that really. Otherwise every validation error would end with "this is not allowed". Yeah duh, otherwise you would allow it and not block me :)